# AWS API gateway rate limiting usage notification for the consumer

Tags: aws-api-gateway, throttling, rate-limiting

Is there a way to notify the client that they are reaching their limit on their usage plan?

Looked at Cloud Watch, unfortunately, doesn't provide usage down to a key level

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to write a [scheduled Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html) function to send notifications to consumers by getting the usage quota using AWS SDK for API Gateway by invoking [getUsagePlan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#getUsagePlan-property) method.

Comment: Is there any update to this question since it is 5 years old? Or is the default approach still to use a Cron job for that?